# How to use Glad in DLL and exe

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, glfw, glad

Is there any way to use Glad within a DLL and exe?  I feel like there may be problems since DLL's have their own memory space that is separate from the exe, but I'm not sure how I would go about refactoring my code to represent this.

My situation is that I have a game engine which contains numerous methods that use OpenGL functions that are loaded by glad, such as the shaders, textures, and anything else rendering related. But, I'm exporting the engine as a dll (for various other reasons), and the runtime editor links to that dll. This runtime editor requires access to the glad functions as well because it statically links to imgui, which needs the same window context and everything, and I'm assuming if I called gladLoadGL() in the dll and in the exe I would get different function pointers which means they wouldn't be operating on the same data. Is there any way to do this? I've tried linking GLFW as a DLL as well, but that doesn't help (which makes sense since this is a glad issue). If I don't do gladLoadGL() in my exe I get nullptr exceptions when trying to execute gl functions (because there are just a couple of cases where I use glFunctions inside the runtime editor). But if I do run gladLoadGL() in my exe, it loads new function pointers which throws everything off and I get errors inside ImGui, which I'm assuming is because glad has loaded different function pointers in the DLL and exe.

Can this be done, or do I need to rethink my overall architecture?

**Edit**: So my original question was answered, and you don't have to do anything special (except load the glad functions in the DLL and exe). However this raises a new problem within my code, which seems to be where the actual problem was. Right now I have a class in the DLL that looks something like this:

```cpp
// In the DLL
class __declspec(dllexport) Application 
{
  Application();

  void Construct(); // I added this because the base constructor would not be called

  virtual void SomeFunc() {} // These are overridden by whoever inherits this class
  virtual void SomeOtherFunc() {}
}

// In the exe
class MyApp : public Application
{
  MyApp() 
  { 
    Construct() // This raises a runtime exception that says the method could not be found. 
    //Is there any way to make sure I export and import this correctly as well?
  }
}
```

**Edit 2**: It turns out I was just missing a build step and never copying my dll to where the exe was located. Thanks again for all the help though

Comment: "*I would get different function pointers which means they wouldn't be operating on the same data*" Why do you think that would be the case?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because the dll has its own virtual memory. So when the dll calls glLoad it loads function pointers into its memory space, then when I call glLoad in the exe it loads new function pointers into its memory space. If my understanding of how dlls are executed on the operating system is correct, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, your understanding is not correct. It is correct that if you don't export glad's function pointers froim your DLL, you will need a separate set for the rest, but this had nothing to do with memory spaces (and a whole _process_ will use its own address space, not each libraries it loads), but with symbol visibility during dynamic linking. The GL function pointers are per GL-context (or even actually per ICD in windows), so you'll get the same function pointers if you query them for the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember the distinction between a pointer variable and what it points to. If you have one instance of GLAD in a DLL and another in an EXE, then for each GLAD function pointer, you will have two pointer variables.

However, they will both point to the *same function*. They are after all loading function pointers for the same OpenGL context. So those pointers will point to the same functions.

So while you will technically be wasting some storage size (since the DLL and EXE both need pointer variables), it should still function just fine, so long as the OpenGL context is current when you load the pointers.

Comment: Thank you @NicolBolas . That narrowed it down for me, it turns out I wasn't creating the context in the DLL. However this does raise another question for me. Right now I have a subclass in the exe inheriting from the superclass in the dll, and when I try to export the class it says it cannot find the superclass's methods. I'll edit my question above with a code snippet, I know this is a different question now but it would still be awesome if you have any insight. I'm marking this as correct though since it answered the original question :)